# Pass data from function and return data using promise

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need help to make this promise working.

I just want to call a function and pass a *pseudo* param and return the results.

Actually it returns undefined

```
function maFonctionAsynchrone(pseudo) {

    var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            connection.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE MATCH (username) AGAINST ('" + pseudo + "')", function (error, results, fields) {
                if (!!error) {
                    console.log('erreur');
                    reject(error)
                } else {
                    resolve(results)
                    return results
                }
            });
    });
}



app.post('/sendnewpost', function(req, res){
    console.log(maFonctionAsynchrone('pseudotest'))
});
```

Comment: what isn't working? any error or something?

Comment: Where was *undefined* returned?

Comment: @LW001 
console.log(maFonctionAsynchrone('pseudotest')) return undefined ( the results is not empty )

Comment: @LasithaPetthawadu he came from the console.log(maFonctionAsynchrone('pseudotest'))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your not returning the promise object from the `maFonctionAsynchrone` function.

Use `return new Promise(function(resolve, reject)` within the async function.

Once you return the promise you can assign a ***then*** or a ***catch*** block to get the result once the promise is resolved asynchronously.

Check the code below

```
function maFonctionAsynchrone(pseudo) {

    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            connection.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE MATCH (username) AGAINST ('" + pseudo + "')", function (error, results, fields) {
                if (!!error) {
                    console.log('erreur');
                    reject(error)
                } else {
                    resolve(results)
                    return results
                }
            });
    });
}

app.post('/sendnewpost', function(req, res){
   maFonctionAsynchrone('pseudotest').then(function(result){
      console.log(result);
   }).catch(function(error){
      console.log(error);
   });
});
```

Check [this](https://www.datchley.name/es6-promises/) link for more examples

Comment: Oh my god, I tried a similar thing like this and it didn't work... now it works.. Thank you so much